# Why are dynamic class methods specified with the double colon notation?

Tags: php, class, methods, static

This is puzzling me: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

```
public string DateInterval::format ( string $format )
```

The method is not static, yet it is given the double colons. What's the reasoning here?

Comment: That's just the manual authors trying to confuse newcomers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's nothing more than PHP authors'/developers' way of writing a method name qualified by its class. It isn't related to the static/dynamic nature of a method.

You'll spot this notation in PHP's errors as well. For example,

```
$o = new stdClass;
$o->method();
```

produces this error:

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined method stdClass::method()

Comment: As to why they couldn't have written something like `DateTime->format()` instead, I'm not one of the team so I can't say much...